# Duplicates in sub-report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have crystal report with a sub report in it. The sub report is displaying duplicates. To avoid that I used below formula.

```
{table.IDField} = previous({table.IDField})
```

Now, duplicates are removed but I have sum of the field in the footer. All the duplicate values are added to the sum. Is there a way that I can select distinct records in the sub report?

Comment: You can check option select distinct records in databse menu or you need to check linking why it is producing duplicate records

Comment: The option is checked @Siva Where else can I check for the links? I am a newbie sorry if this is not something that I should ask

Comment: Go to database expert to check links

Comment: Thanks @Siva
Database expert didn't solve my problem as the data is redundant. I grouped them as required and solved the issue. It works fine now

Comment: may be you could post your solution as Answer for others to get something out of this page.

Comment: Sure :) Will post the procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed below steps to solve this issue.

1. Created a group on the IDField
2. Moved all the fields from detail section to the above group header.
3. Suppressed the detail section.
4. Created the below formula and placed it in group header. I have supressed this because I didn't have to display this.

   ```
   whileprintingrecords;
       numbervar totalOfIDField := totalOfIDField + {IDField};
       "";
   ```
5. Created a formula to display the above field (totalOfIDField).

   ```
   whileprintingrecords;
   numbervar taotalOfIDField;
   ```

   This should be placed in the corresponding Group Footer.
6. Created a formula to reset the totalOfIDField each time group changes. Included this in the Main Group Header.

   ```
   whileprintingrecords;
   numbervar totalOfIDField := 0;
   ```